# Can someone help me to find why there's no output?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
   char str[50];
   int count[26] = {0};
   int x;
   int len;
   int max;

printf("Enter your input: ");
scanf("%s", str);

while( ! feof(stdin)) {
  len = strlen(str);
  for(x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
    char ch = str[x];
    int sub = ch - 97;
    count[sub] = count[sub] + 1;
  }
  scanf("%s", str);
}
max = count[0];
for(x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
    if(count[x] > max){
      max = count[x];
    }
}

printf("Missing letters: ");
for(x = 0; x < 26; ++x) {
  if(count[x] == 0) {
    x = x + 97;
    printf("%c", x);
  }
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

I'm new to `C` and I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now and I'm just not understanding. I think the issue is with the `while` loop, but I've just started coding I have no idea. Does anything jump out at anyone? This is supposed to *read a sentence and output the letters that were not seen*. Thank you.

Comment: Aside: please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `x = x + 97;` is suspect, because `x` is the loop control.

Comment: Thank you, Weather. I actually just took the while loop out completely and it works perfectly!

Comment: Usually its a good idea not to remove your question after getting an answer so that others may stumble upon your question and find the answer too

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions.

Comment: @spectacularbob: that was not "removing", that was vandalizing.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop only terminates when there is an EOF. Use Ctrl^D to send the EOF signal to escape the feof function.